# ZoneEdit API examples

Tags: json, api

If anyone has experience using the ZoneEdit API, I'd be grateful for your guidance. I've been trying to use it for a hour now and have gotten nowhere.

I started with a simple service, the getIP method in their UTIL service, doing:

```
curl -X POST -i -d "{'action':'getIP'} -H "Content-Type: text/json" https://newapi.zoneedit.com/Util.action
```

All I ever get in response though is:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Unknown directive: ''","map":[]}
```

Their docs: [introduction](http://www.zoneedit.com/doc/api/intro.html), [util methods](http://www.zoneedit.com/doc/api/util.html)

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ZoneEdit api but I got the same error you did until I modified the request as follows:

```
curl -X POST -i -d "action=getIP" https://newapi.zoneedit.com/Util.action
```

That returned my IP address in plain text.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you, it's working fine and seems to work for all other services.

Comment: They must not take JSON as input.  That's strange because that's the default format they return data in. (at least according to the documentation...)